# I want to make a sticky menu using kivy's screenmanager

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make a stickymenu like this

[image: Here is image]

yeah looks like iosApp menubar. I already know i should use screenmanager but i understood it can use only Class of Screen. If i hope use in Boxlayout class.But i dont know it. If somebody tell me how make like this menu.

I forgot to write important things.
The menu that I want to make is in a state where it is fixed without making a transition for each menu when making a page transition.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [kivymd](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD) that already has this kind of menu. It's called `MDBottomNavigation` there:

[image]

Example of how to create it [can be found](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/demos/kitchen_sink/main.py#L823) inside demos.

Comment: Now!! I collected setup this!!
Thank you. And i love u doc!!
Maybe i can do what i want!!